# Vector push_back causing Unhandled exception

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

Everything is working until the compiler tries to perform the push_back operation.
in the if condition proper values are being returned.
I have declared  items as:

```
vector<int> items; // inside the header file.
```

//inside the .cpp file

```
void MsPs::findnSort()
{
    for(int i = 1; i<50 ; i++)
    {

        string temp = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << i) )->str();    // TO convert int i to a string temp
        if(findSupport(temp) >= MIS[i])
        {
            items.push_back(i);
        }

    }

}
```

the following error pops up:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5052ad4a (msvcp100d.dll) in PrefixScan.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x3d4cccd1.
```

PS: I have one more function using the push_back operation and there it's working fine.

Can anyone help me with this?

Even this gives the same error:

```
void MsPs::findnSort()
{
    for(int i = 1; i<50 ; i++)
    {

        items.push_back(i);
    }


}
```

Comment: what's the size of `MIS`?

Comment: Its size is 50, but while debugging, the code isn't going through even the first pass.

Comment: Memory is corrupted somewhere else, use debugger to see the call stack, should find something wrong

Comment: I'm not sure what to look for?

Comment: Why is your index `i` starting at `1` and not `0` ?

Comment: Why do you declare `vector<int> items` in the header file? Is it a shared header? Where is the vector actually instanced?

Comment: I'm trying to insert the number which i  corresponds to. like 1,2,3...

Comment: BTW, if you had C++11, you could save yourself a lot of trouble with: `string temp = std::to_string(i);`

Comment: @Brett A static instance will be created when the header is included in the source file and compiled into a binary.  Of course the OP will get multiple definition errors if he included is in other implementation files and links them into the same binary, but that wasn't the issue in the original post.

Comment: @ChrisHayden. No, it will not be a *static* instance - it will be an exported symbol in every translation unit that includes the header.

Comment: @Brett You're right.  Should not have used static there.  If it were static there would be no multiple definition errors.  Good catch. +1.

Comment: So, I want to insert the value of the index, into the vector if some condition is true, How do I do that.

Comment: Your vector is most likely corrupted already from some other part of your code.

Comment: Its not being used at any other part.

Comment: @ChrisHayden - which makes me wonder if the `push_back` is operating on the intended instance? e.g., the linker is discarding multiple instances? It shouldn't of course - not in the way multiple instances of template code are.

Comment: It doesn't have to be used, something else may be corrupting it by writing over the memory it occupies.

Comment: Alright thanks guys, for now, I just used an array instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that the ostringstream is destructed when the static cast returns.  Thus your pointer is dangling when `str()` is called.  Try this instead:

```
void MsPs::findnSort()
{
    for(int i = 1; i<50 ; i++)
    {
        ostringstream blah;
        string temp = (blah << i).str();

        if(findSupport(temp) >= MIS[i])
        {
            items.push_back(i);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Eventhis is giving the same error:
void MsPs::findnSort()
{
 for(int i = 1; i<50 ; i++)
 {
  
  
   items.push_back(i);
 

 }

}

Comment: @AdRoiT : Sounds to me like you're calling `findnSort` on a null or otherwise invalid pointer to an `MsPs` object.